# TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I can't seem to figure this out. I am trying an exercise online and when I try passing an event on my child component I get an error "cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined" error. Here is my code.

```
import React from "react";
import TodoItems from "./TodoItems";
import TodoComponent from "./TodoComponent";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todoanItem: TodoItems
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(id) {
    this.setState(function(state) {
      const newstate = state.todoanItem.map(function(todo) {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.complete = !todo.complete;
        }
        return todo;
      });
      return {
        todoanItem: newstate
      };
    });
  }
  render() {
    const theItems = this.state.todoanItem.map(function(item) {
      return (
        <TodoComponent
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
          handleClick={this.handleClick}
        />
      );
    });
    return <div>{theItems}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";
class TodoComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="todo-items">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.props.item.completed}
          onChange={event => this.props.handleClick(this.props.item.id)}
        />
        <p>{this.props.item.todo}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default TodoComponent;
```

Comment: You don't have a constructor in the `TodoComponent`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava have added a constructor and gotten Useless constructor  no-useless-constructor

Comment: Did you even read the question link I posted?

Comment: Yes I have @AnuragSrivastava

Comment: No it doesn't work I have tried that same error @AnuragSrivastava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an arrow function in the `render` function of `App`:

```
const theItems = this.state.todoanItem.map((item) => { // Here
  return (
    <TodoComponent
      key={item.id}
      item={item}
      handleClick={this.handleClick}
    />
  );
});
```

Also, add a constructor in the `TodoComponent`:

```
constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
}
```